# Number of intersections at singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ be plane algebraic curves. If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are their degrees, then the number of intersections (if finite) is at most $d_1\cdot d_2$. But if we know, that every point of intersection $p$ is also a singular point at any of the two curves, how does that affect this bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the intersection multiplicity of $C_1$ and $C_2$ at $P$ is greater than or equal to the product of the multiplicities of $C_1$ in $P$ and $C_2$ in $P$, i.e. $I(C_1,C_2;P) \geq \mu_P(C_1)\mu_P(C_2)$. As $$d_1d_2=\sum_{P\in C_1\cap C_2} I(C_1,C_2;P) \geq \sum_{P\in C_1\cap C_2} \mu_P(C_1)\mu_P(C_2)$$ and $\mu_P(C) > 1$ iff $P$ is a singular point of $C$, we can say that $|C_1\cap C_2| \leq \frac{d_1d_2}{4}$ if all points of intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$ are singular points of both $C_1$ and $C_2$ (if you were asking about the case when every point of intersection is singular on at least one, but not necessarily both, of the curves, then you'd get the bound $|C_1\cap C_2| \leq \frac{d_1d_2}{2}$).